# Use xib without a view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xib

I need to create several similar views
In a easy way,I create some views in xib(each full screen)

And I have a view controller to use this xib's views,code like this:

```
NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXibName" owner:nil options:nil];
[self.view addSubview:[views objectAtIndex:aIndex]];
```

At this moment,view shows alright.

Now,there's some buttons in those views,so I connect a outlet for each view

**bad thing happened**

app crashed due to

> **uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x969db50> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key**

Analyse:
Although my xib file's "File Owner" has been set,but there's no connection between xib and the only view controller.

How could I get the pointer of a view's button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
NSNib*      aNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyGreatNib" bundle:nil];
NSArray*    topLevelObjs = nil;

for (SomeClass *obj in myOwnerObjects) {
    topLevelObjs = nil;

    if (![aNib instantiateNibWithOwner:obj topLevelObjects:&topLevelObjs])
    {
        NSLog(@"Warning! Could not load nib file.\n");
        return;
    }

    for (id topLevelObj in topLevelObjs) {
        if ([topLevelObj isKindOfClass:[NSView class]]) {
            NSView *otView = (NSView *)topLevelObj;
            // set frame...
            [self addSubview:otView];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops...
I just found something.

```
UINib* xib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyXibName" bundle:nil];
UIView* view = [[xib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] lastObject];
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

You can design xib as per your need by defining class UIView

Code in .m file:

```
NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Interface" owner:nil options:nil];

UIView* mainView = [objects objectAtIndex:0];

for (UIView* view in [mainView subviews]) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel* label = (UILabel*)view;
        //....As You Wish...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Default implementation of -loadView creates the view or loads NIB. As far as I know, there is no way to know the final size of the view at time of creation in -loadView. So the default view size is set to `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].` This is because it may be difficult to work work with zero frame view in -viewDidLoad and other methods.

Your one-line implementation may look like this:

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
}
```

You don't need to set the autoresizing mask, because you don't know in what context the view will be displayed. The caller is responsible to set you correct frame, autoresizing mask and similar external attributes (I call them like this).

Imagine this in a UINavigationController method:

```
// we are pushing new VC, view is accessed for the first time
pushedVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(...);
```

It is setting the correct frame, but your -loadView is called just before that -setFrame:. So during -viewDidLoad you have temporary non-zero frame, just to be able to setup subviews and internal autoresizing. After this, the correct frame is set to you and in -viewWillAppear: you have final frame.